# User Explorer in GA4 started showing all values multiplied by 2

Tags: google-analytics-4

User Explorer in Google Analytics 4 for games started multiplying all metrics by 2.

In the following example, the metrics should be 1 (GA4 by some reason multiplies it by 1000000), but now it becomes 2.

[Explorer Example View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHZUL.png)

How to fix this?

I checked BigQuery and Looker Studio, and they all show the correct value (1) for this event.